# Is there any caching feature in Phoenix framework?

Tags: web, elixir

[Phoenix framework](http://www.phoenixframework.org/) is just like rails. But rails provide a cache solution: `Rails.cache`.

Is the any similar feature in Phoenix framework? Or caching is different in Elixir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a cache specifically for Phoenix; however I'm not as expert on Phoenix as I am on other aspects of Elixir.  That said there is this: https://github.com/sasa1977/con_cache

Normally if I were wanting a cache for any Elixir app I'd check https://hex.pm first.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind talking about in what field you are using Elixir?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Cachex](https://github.com/zackehh/cachex):

```
result = %{a => 1}
Cachex.set(:apicache,  "ajax" , result, [ ttl: :timer.seconds(1800)])
Cachex.get(:apicache, "ajax")
```